# Question about jar files

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm trying to download a mod on minecraft but every time I press a jar file it opens then closes again straight away. Any ways around this? Btw im a beginner

Comment: Depending on your mod loader, you might have to put the .jar file in a specific folder. Follow the instructions of whatever mod loader you want to use (an example is Fabric).

Answer (score 3):

You are doing this wrong.

1. First off you need to install the mod loader for the mod, the most
   common are forge and fabric. Remember, this has to be the right
   version (eg 1.12.2 forge for a 1.12.2 mod)
2. After you do that you need to move the jar into your .minecraft/mods
   folder, on windows this folder is located in appdata.
3. Once that's done open the minecraft launcher and select the
   installation for the mod loader you installed. If it doesn't show up
   click on the installation tab and create a new installation with the
   mod loader version selected.
4. You may also want to allocate more ram by changing the advanced
   settings, I'd recommend you follow a tutorial for that.
5. Then press play, it might ask you if you want to play the modified
   version of minecraft, just click yes. That should be all the steps,
   you might need to install libraries for some mods so make sure you
   do that.

Comment: To also clarify, clicking on a jar file won't do anything.

Comment: @Potterton for mods it usually wont, but often you have to open jars to install mod loaders and minecraft itself is a jar.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I don't often deal with mods so my knowledge is limited.

Comment: @Topcode but the `.jar` like in minecraft is started by another process, not clicked

Comment: @Penguin usually, but if i wanna open mc by click the jar i will